# Show duplicates from two different tables using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

In ArcGIS Pro, I have a shapefile of parcel boundaries mapped out. I also have a list of new applications for these parcels in Excel. I want to be able to compare the excel list with the shapefile attribute table and have all the ones that overlap be selected. Both tables share a field.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I'd look into using an attribute join.